# Is there any way to generate in-app purchase receipts without an actual app?

Tags: android, ios, automated-tests, in-app-purchase

I want to write integration tests for purchasing an in-app purchase, submitting it to the backend for verification and work done on top of it. These tests are run automatically before deploying our backend.

Is there any way to generate them without an actual app?

I am currently hardcoding a test receipt/purchase token from both iOS and Android but it is not enough for all tests AND Google stops validating them after 60 days of expiration.

If not, what options do I have? Is there a way to emulate the app using a service of some sort perhaps?

Comment: Assuming your app talks to an API, you should be able to simulate the app and talk to the API directly yourself.

Comment: well, the purchase verification step where the backend sends the purchase to the google/apple transaction verification servers is in my way. if it is not a legit purchase receipt or token, i cannot do anything I want because the verification step fails. i cannot generate a legit one without the app.